# UI5 TileContainer is blank in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, sapui5

I am using SAPUI5 with HANA DB to create a custom dashboard.

I need to add a `CustomTile` (with different layout and content) in the `onInit` function of my controller by the below code. It works perfectly fine in Firefox. But in Chrome, the tile is simply not shown and I also can't find it within the HTML elements:

```js
onInit: function() {
  var oTileContainer = this.getView().byId("tileContainer");
  var quantTile = new sap.m.CustomTile({/* Some content ... */});
  oTileContainer.insertTile(quantTile, 0);
},
```

For completeness, here is the relevant part of my XML view:

```xml
<TileContainer id="tileContainer" tiles="{/TileCollection}">
  <CustomTile>
    <!-- Some content ... -->
  </CustomTile>
</TileContainer>
```

Does anyone have any idea why it might not be shown/rendered within Chrome, but in Firefox? Is there any procedure that I can call that forces a re-render or something similar?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Page Is Blank Without Throwing Any Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50922382/page-is-blank-without-throwing-any-errors)

Comment: Take a look at the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51042269/5846045) there. It's the same issue. `TileContainer` had a bug which is fixed now.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe Chrome is mixing up the binding with the fixed tile.

You could create a local JSON model with the data from your hana service AND your fixed tile and then bind your tile container with your local service.